# I want to use Devise a user table with association another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to generate the 'Profile' data at the time of User preservation at the time of following constitution

How to do something?

users table data

```
+-------+-------------------+----------+-----+--------------------+
| id    | email             | nickname | sex | encrypted_password |
+-------+-------------------+----------+-----+--------------------+
| 95425 | example@gmail.com | Citrus   | 1   |                    |
+-------+-------------------+----------+-----+--------------------+
```

profiles table data

```
+---------+------------+-------------+
| user_id | birth_year | birth_month |
+---------+------------+-------------+
| 95425   | 1982       | 12          |
+---------+------------+-------------+
```

signup.html.slim

```
= f.label :sex, 'Mens', :value => 0
= f.radio_button :sex, true, :checked => true
= f.label :sex, 'Women', :value => 1
= f.radio_button :sex, false
= f.text_field :email
= f.password_field :password_confirmation
= fields_for :profile do |c|
  = c.date_select(:birth_year, use_month_numbers: true,start_year:1930, end_year:       Time.now.year,date_separator: '/') %>
```

Comment: what error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

its good to have a `user profile` but i would **recommend** to do this after signup as i believe signup should be as simple as possible just by using users `email/username` and `date of birth` and `password`..thats it.I have implemented the same but i **create a default profile** for every user using observer once user is saved using devise.this is what i did.You can have a `profile` association with `user` model and `profile_pictures` associated with every `profile` that `belongs to` `user`.This is what i did:-

1. first `signup` form using just `email,password,date of birth and current location`
2. then i use this data in my `observer` to create `default profile` as shown below

**my user.rb**

```
 has_one :profile,:dependent => :destroy
```

**my profile.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :profile_pictures, :class_name => 'ProfilePicture', :dependent => :destroy
```

**My user_observer.rb**

```
class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

  ##this method will run after every user is created and will create a new default profile
   def after_create(user)
    Rails.logger.info  "creating default profile pic for #{user.email}=================="
   ##first get username from email id removing @ and other extra fields
    if user.provider.blank?
      name = user.email[/[^@]+/]
      name=name.split(".").map {|n| n.capitalize }.join(" ")
      user.username = name
    end
    ##here i create a new profile with that username
    user.create_profile(:title=>user.username)
       default_profile_picture=user.profile.profile_pictures.new({
       :avatar => File.new("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/dashboard/default_avatar.jpg"),
       :active => true  
       })
    default_profile_picture.save
   ##save the user with default profile(with default profile picture)
    user.save!
   ##send a welcome mail to new user as well using sidekiq with redis
   UserMailer.delay.registration_confirmation(user)

   end

end
```

HOPE THIS HELPS....